# Visual Studio Community 2013 のインストールイメージをダウンロードするには？

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoftより Visual Studio Community 2013が発表されました。
使ってみたいのですが、どこから入手できますか？

Comment: 質問者が質問者なだけありプロモーションに感じられます。
このようなプロモーションはむしろタグWikiに直接書いていただいたほうが歓迎されるかと思います。

Comment: DVされすぎな気もします。マイナスになる程度で十分です。

Answer (score -2):

<del>[Visual Studio Community 2013 の説明ページ](http://www.visualstudio.com/ja-jp/dn469161)からも辿れますが</del>、下記のリンクをご利用ください。

> 注：現在ではVS2015が公開されているため、上記ページもVS2015の紹介になっています。メニューの「ダウンロード」から「[すべてのダウンロード](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)」とたどることで現在でもCommunity2013をダウンロードすることができます。

[Visual Studio Community 2013 の ISO イメージ](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9863609)

[Visual Studio Community 2013 の日本語パック](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832174)